# android ViewPager:know when a page is no longer the current

Tags: android

hi mate i have to know when a page is no longer the current.
i think that i have to use Listener, i see that exist:

```
@Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
```

but there arent listener to know when page X is no longer active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "no longer active" but the onPageSelected gives the new index so you could do something like this:

```
private currentPage = 0;
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if(position != currentPage){ //page has changed to 
        currentPage = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: i mean this: if the current page is the 1, and then user scroll to pag 2, i want to intercept "pag1 is no longer the current pag"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `onPageScrolled` method to understand that the active page was changed.

From the documentation:

```
This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled, either as part of a
 programmatically initiated smooth scroll or a user initiated touch scroll.
```

Therefore `onPageScrolled` method should do the trick.

Comment: if the user only do a scroll that dont change the page ?

Comment: No, onPageScrolled method is **only** invoked when a scroll is applied and current page is changed. Therefore this method is not affected from normal scrolling.